# What's the meaning of "he fears that peace might have to wait"?

Tags: meaning

> he fears that *peace* might have to wait.

Does it mean:

> he fears that he might have to wait for that peace?

Or it means something else?

The fuller text is:

> He knew it was better not to get involved, with any of it. Not with
>   her, and not with Matthew. He’s had enough trouble. What he wants now
>   is peace. But he fears that peace might have to wait.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. It means, "He fears that he might have to wait for that peace".

Answer (score 0):

It's the peace that will have to wait. The troubles will continue for longer, but when they finally finish, peace will take over. So, in fact, he also fears that that peace won't come any time soon.